# HA on Yarn Timelineserver and MapReduce JobHistoryserver

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, high-availability

Some Yarn services, like the ResourceManager, support High Availability.

After looking through the corresponding documentation of both the Timelineserver and the JobHistory, I haven't been able to see if that feature is supported for these 2 services. I have also been looking through the different properties of the corresponding configuration files ([yarn-site](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) and [mapred-site](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)) and haven't found anything either.

I found it strange that HA is not supported for none of the services mentioned.

Is it really not possible to enable such feature on both the Timelineserver and JobHistoryserver?

Has anyone been able to enable it?

Note: I have tried putting 2 hosts in properties such as `yarn.timeline-service.webapp.address` from yarn-site.xml, but it prints out errors.